# Remove Bottom 3 scores in file

Tags: python, file

```
numberofbands = int(input("How many bands are there in the competition? "))

print("Input each band’s name pressing enter after each one") 

file = open("scores.txt","w") 
for loop in range(numberofbands): 
  name = input("\nEnter the name of the band: ") 
  votes = input("Enter how many votes that band received: ")
  file.write(name + "," + votes + "," + "\n") 
file.close() 

number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))

def removebottom3():
#code to remove bottom 3 here

removebottom3()
```

The first part writes the band's name and score to the file.

I want the code to remove the lowest 3 scoring bands from the file. There will be a function for that.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "could you help", do you mean "do it for me", or what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Please see [why this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite off. Let me help you.

First, consider using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), it is meant for this kind of cases.
Second, try dividing the script logic into blocks (divide and conquer!), first get the data, then sort and remove the last 3, and only at the end write the results to a file.

Here is an example of the implementation.

```
from collections import Counter

numberofbands = int(input("How many bands are there in the competition? "))

print("Input each band’s name pressing enter after each one") 


scores = Counter()

for n in range(numberofbands):
    name = input("\nEnter the name of the band: ")
    vote = input("Enter how many votes that band received: ")
    scores.update({name:int(votes)}) 


#remove the last 3
final = scores.most_common()[:-3]

#write to file
with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name, vote in final:
        f.write(f'{name},{vote}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, correct me if I'm wrong but I understand that scores.update... creates are dictionary. However, for final... I don't understand why most_common() is used, wouldn't that search for the most occurrences, not the lowest in value. And why is [:-3] not inside the brackets as you are using most_common?

Comment: @Daniel `scores` is not a standard dictionary but a Counter. It has some extra methods among which `most_common()` that sorts the underlying dictionary by values and returns a list of tuples `(key, value)` sorted by the value. `[:-3]` takes the whole list excluding the last 3 values. Please read the Python documentation for Counter, it is quite clear, and just play with it a bit. You will find Counter extremely useful in many similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

since you are already reading all the lines from the file,

```
number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))
```

you can use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) to sort your lines by score,

```
lines = open("scores.txt").readlines()
sorted(lines, 
       key=lambda x : float(x.split(",")[1]),
       reverse = True)
```